# Stop Visual Studio from launching a new browser window when starting debug?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer, browser

I already have a window open with the web site I'm debugging. I don't need VS to launch another one for me every time I need to debug.

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Do you have tabbed browsing enabled?.. And are you using IE?

Comment: You want to disable the Browser Link Feature

Comment: [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73945327/1042705) for VS 2022. [Launch profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73945327/1042705)

Answer (score 492, accepted):

Open your startup project's properties (*Project → {ProjectName} Properties...* from the main menu or right click your project in the *Solution Explorer* and choose *Properties*), then navigate to the *Web* tab and under *Start Action* choose *Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application*.

You will still be able to use any browser (or Fiddler, whatever) to access the running application, but it won't open the browser window automatically, it'll just start in the background and wait for any requests.

Comment: That seems like a really good solution, but just like Slace's, it doesn't stop execution at breakpoints, it says no symbols are loaded. Thanks though.

Comment: It does. I use it for debugging all the time. You must have wrong configuration. Double check that you have debugging enabled in the web.config and that you're running a Debug build.

Comment: Well, at least for web service projects, when started breakpoints get hit as soon as the first client calls a web service method.

Comment: Only problem with this is the rest of my team actually likes it when the browser opens.  So I have a modified csproj which slows me down a lot when committing changes.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr I'd swear this is a per user setting that is local... Perhaps you have .csproj.user file checked-in (you shouldn't).

Comment: So it is [a local setting]. I had previously assumed that all the project settings in that area were stored in team csproj.  I had previously tried changing the URL that the browser would open by modifying "Project URL" and saw that it got changed in .csproj. Upon closer inspection, I now see that there is a "Apply server settings to all users" checkmark which controls just that field.  My bad.

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak This doesn't seem to work. It opens the new tab regardless of checking the setting.

Comment: This will not work if you have to use another setting for "Start Action", such as "Start external program ". In that case, @Joao Costa's answer below works great.

Comment: For Visual Studio on Mac, the comparable settings is under "Project > Options > Run > Default > ASP.NET Core".  Uncheck the "Open URL in web browser when app starts".

Comment: And don't forget to stop the running app or else all options are grayed out!

Comment: @Bouke This is THE solution. In VS2022 it exactly works for me like I expected. Which other "other upvoted answer" do you mean? There are (and already were when you commented) a few of them...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I’m not sure why I wrote that. This answer seems fine.

Answer (score 272):

For VS 15.7.1 `Tools` → `Options` → `Projects and Solutions` → `Web Projects` → uncheck `Stop debugger when browser window is closed`.

Comment: VS 15 is Visual Studio **2017**, BTW.

Comment: Suggested change don't do what the question is about.

Comment: Works fine in VS2019 (16.4.4)

Comment: For me, this is true answer. vs2019 16.8.3

Comment: Also works in VS2022 RC3 (ie Version 17.0.0 RC3)

Comment: Also works in VS2022 RTM

Comment: This is the correct answer to the poster's problem - the accepted answer stops a browser being opened at all, this one prevents additional browsers being opened with each successive launch of an application.

Comment: @Tom If sker accepted the answer you could imagine that it is the answer he was looking for. The question post says: "I already have a window open with the web site I'm debugging." - so he wants to stop "a browser being opened at all".

Comment: Works fine in VS2019

Comment: after more than a decade, I still need to visit this page...

Answer (score 140):

Updated answer for a .NET Core Web Api project...

Right-click on your project, select "Properties," go to "Debug" and untick the "Launch browser" checkbox (enabled by default).

[image]

Comment: @Grey Where is this option "Launch Browser"option present?

Comment: I've updated the answer: You've to go to the properties of your project to get to the option.

Comment: it has changed for [VS 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73945327/1042705)..

Answer (score 81):

In an ASP.Net 5 project this can now be set for each launch profile.

Open the file **launchsettings.json** under the Startup Project Properties folder and add `"launchBrowser": false` to the profile you are configuring, such as in:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer which I was looking for Thanks

Answer (score 41):

In Visual Studio 2019, I resolved the same issue as below:

Go to your Visual Studio options **Tools** >>> **Options** >>> **Project and Solutions** >>> **Web Projects** then finally **untick** option >>> **Stop debugger browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops**

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**
untick option >>> **Stop debugger browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops**

[image]

**Step 3:**

Then finally click on >>> **OK** button, these are all the steps to resolve the issue.

Comment: This answer works even for visual studio 2019 Preview (Version 16.8.0 Preview 6.0)

Comment: Magic, also works for VS 2022

Answer (score 28):

I have solved my problem by following below steps.
Go to Tools >> Click on options >> click on projects and solutions >> web projects >>
uncheck "Stop debugging when browser is closed" option[image]

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: I was looking for a way to stop visual studio from launching a new browser when starting debug, but open a new tab in current browser instead. It makes no sense why, but disabling this makes it work.

Answer (score 23):

As I did not had the mentioned option in my VS which is Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, I had to look for some other option.

Here is it what I've found:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging tab(General) and uncheck "Enable JavaScript debugging for Asp.Net(Chrome and IE).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, This solution working fine on VS 2022 (v17.7.7).

Answer (score 22):

This workaround works for me for VS 2019

> Tools => Options

Then type `Projects and solutions` in the search box.

Select the `Web Projects`.

Then deselect the option below.

> Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops.

This works for me. Hope this will help.

Comment: It still opens a new tab every time when I start debugging.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like it has changed for VS 2022,

Now it has a dedicated UI,

***Right Click*** the project (in Solution explorer) > select ***Properties*** then follow :-

[image]

[image]
"*uncheck*" the option for it to not open automatically.

**OR** you can click the menu bar, *Debug > Properties*

[image]

and you can reach the **Step-2** "*launch profiles*" directly from there

**or** a **shortcut**:

Select the project ( in Solution explorer) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then follow from there..

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Attach To Process function, rather than pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

This can also allow you to navigate through known working sections without the slowdown of VS debugger loaded underneath.

Comment: I've tried that, but it won't stop execution when it finds a breakpoint. I need it to stop at breakpoints, is there a way to enable that? Thanks.

Comment: provided that your attached to a process which has loaded the exact same assemblies which are in the /bin/ folder of the application all breakpoints will work (oh, and provided there are .pdb files!)

Comment: I Googled on how to fix that but it seems like a lot of trouble. I couldn't get it to work. I'll use I Have the Hat's solution in the meanwhile. Thank you.

Comment: I can debug by pressing F5 with the "wait for a request from an external application" option, but I can't get Attach To Process to work (attaching to INetMgr.exe). Never stops at a breakpoint. I was using VSCommands in VS 2013, but the new 2015 version of VSCommands doesn't support "Attach to IIS" yet. Wish I knew what the issue was.

Answer (score 9):

When you first open a web/app project, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>, which is the shortcut for starting the application without debugging. Then when you subsequently hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and launch the debugger, it will use that instance of IE. Then stop and start the debugging in Visual Studio instead of closing IE.

It works on my machines. I'm using the built in dev web server. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Firefox will also stay open so you can debug in either or both at the same time.

Comment: Hey that works! Thanks a lot. Now I can avoid around 100 extra windows per coding session. Also, when I hit F5 VS resizes my IE window. Do you know how can I avoid that?

Comment: Sorry sker, I don't know the answer to that--it doesn't happen for me doing the above though, so there probably is an answer somewhere. Maybe IE is remembering its window size and it's unrelated to the debugging scenario?

Answer (score 9):

Here's what did it for me:

Go to **Project Properties > Debug > Uncheck "Launch Browser" > Save**.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be one case in which none of the above but the following helps. I'm developing a project for Windows Azure cloud platform and I have a web role. There is indeed a radio button *Don't open page* in *Project -> {Project name} properties...* as was pointed out by Pawel Krakowiak, but it has no effect in my case whatsoever. However, there is the main cloud project in solution explorer and there is the *Roles* folder under it. If I right click my web role in this folder and choose *Properties*, I get another set of settings and on the *Configuration* tab there is the *Launch browser for* flag, after unchecking it a new browser window is not opened on application start up.

Answer (score 7):

Joao Costa answer also holds true for .Net core 2 projects.

launchsettings.json  --> "launchBrowser": **false**

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Worth noting that this launchSettings.json is hidden under Properties "Folder" in "Solution Explorer"

Answer (score 4):

While there are several excellent answers, ranging from [usual suspects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/716757/5040900) to [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211917/5040900) solutions, I would like to provide one more to the fray that addresses **what you should do when you are working on a solution with multiple projects**.

Before I arrived at this solution, I kept looking at **`bindingInformation`** in the applicationhost.config of the solution, tirelessly looking for any hint of why things were simply not working.

> Turns out, the **simple** thing that I overlooked was that different projects have individual settings too.
>
> So, besides `Project > {Project-Name} Properties... > Web > Start Action` on my Backend Project, I also had to Go to `Website > Start Options... > Start Action` on my Frontend Project. Once there, I selected `Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application` and have been happy ever since!

[image: Backend Settings]
[image: Frontend Settings]

Answer (score 3):

I looked over the answers and didn't see the solution I found mentioned. If it was, my apologies. In my case, currently using Visual Studio 2015. In the solution explorer, right click on the Project file and click properties. Go to the Debug tab and this should have info for how you're launching "IIS Express or Web(DNX)" for the first two drop downs, and then there should be a checkmark box for "Launch URL:". Uncheck this option and your browser won't be automatically launched everytime you go to debug your application. Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on your project, then choose `Properties` , on `Debug` tab you should uncheck `launch browser` checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> if your amends are front end only

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can now also get to the Web properties by clicking the dropdown arrow next to the Run button!

1. Click dropdown button next to "Run"
2. *{ Project name }* *Properties*
3. Click "Web" in the list on the left
4. Under the "Start Action" segment, click Don't open a page.

You're all set!

PS: This works for me, I'm on version 16.5.5 of VS Professional 2019 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Web Publish feature in IIS, then the solution I found was to edit the publish configuration and remove the `Destination URL` from the configuration (leave it blank).

If this is defined, then every time you publish the project it will open the URL specified in the `Destination URL` (which is a redirect URL).

Reference: https://support.winhost.com/kb/a1604/visual-studio-publish-web-deploy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For VS2022 and ASP.NET Core:

Another shortcut is: to click the small dropdown button on the right side green-triangle button with the project's name on it, which usually launches the debug build. and then the last option "{project name} Debug Properties" which launches the dedicated UI window directly.

[image]

From there follow @irf's advice:

> "uncheck" the option for it to not open automatically.

[image]