# Visual Studio - debug web app (running local IIS) without starting browser

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis

I have two solutions, SilverLight frontend, REST service backend.  The backend has half a dozen or so distinct WCF services that are each defined in a separate project.  Each service has it's own web configured in my local IIS. I have set multiple start projects on debug as I want to debug all services but I would rather VS did NOT start a browser session for each web app. on debug startup, is this possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/716757/1073107. Looks to do what you want

Comment: Apologies, this is an exact duplicate of above, I have voted to close.

Answer (score 11):

Go to the properties of the web projects and in the Web Tab, set `Start Action` to `Don't open a page`

Comment: Bummer... needs a hotkey so you can hit ctrl+F5 once to push to local iis and launch browsers, then i can hit ctrl+xxx to push server code again and keep my browsers open.