# Suppress Asp.net MVC 4 to run the browser

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net `MVC4` `WEB API` project as a service for a `WPF`client , both projects run when I press `F5` so the browser opens , and I can not avoid this behavior.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Web -> Don't open a page.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I stop Visual Studio from launching a new browser window every single time I hit the Start Debugging button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-every-single-tim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the startup project's configurations, or solution configuration, to ensure you don't have more than one application or project starting simultaneously in development.

This is similar to setting to Azure Web Roles where you can set your web role to startup both the HTTP and HTTPS endpoints so you can end up with two browsers starting up in debug (F5) mode. Easily fixed by accessing the project's properties where it's configured.

Comment: It depends on how your project is configured but look at the comment by @CodeCaster above, that should redirect you in the right location.