# Web api Breakpoint doesn't hit from another project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

In the same solution, I have a project that has Web API functions, and porject the uses it.
I call it from Javascript.
I put break point in my webapi function.
If the html/javascript is in the project where the webapi is, breakpoint hit.
If it is on the other project it doesn't hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to right click your solution, and select 'Select Startup Projects...'

Then choose 'Multiple startup projects' and choose both the web and the Web API project to both have an action of 'Start'.

Comment: Thanks. This works. though a default browser page opens for the webapi project. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Not that I know of, I do get annoyed by it and tend to have to close all the tabs that build up.

Comment: How do you make it at least open in a new tab and not window?

Comment: I debug in Chrome, and it does this by default, so I am not sure.

Comment: Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. I try other things like restart web api, close and reopen visual studio, restart the computer, and occasionally out of desperation copy the .pdb from every project in the solution to every other project in the solution. Then I make a sacrifice by killing myself in Halo. Wait three days and it will work.

Comment: Just to reply to @Giladsefti, in case you didn't know there is a solution to the tab build up http://stackoverflow.com/a/716757/1061602