# Start Visual Studio MVC without attaching a debugger to the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Hi I like to debug my javascript in chrome and my serverside code in VS. Is there a way to tell VS that I don't want to attach a debugger to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Either "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl+F5) or [configure the web application project on the Web tab to "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external applciation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-every-single-tim). The latter option will still let you hit breakpoints and break on exceptions.

See also [MSDN Blogs: Start Debugging vs. Start Without Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging-vstipdebug0037.aspx).