# Visual Studio 2017 .net core 2.0 console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, console-application

Hi I'm new in the visual studio 2017 and .net core 2.0 world. I have started to working on a project of a colleague that in the moment is not at work. It start correctly. Only one thing disturb me a lot:

When I start the application with Visual Studio 2017 then a console (not in VS) appear in the window and a browser opens. When I close the console or the browser the application die. The application has only back end function, so I don't need the browser. Is there some way to:

- tell VS to run the console in an internal window of VS?
- tell VS to not show the browser?

Thank you in advance

P.S: I think this is a more VS setting so I didn't wrote the code. But If you think there are more info that can help you to figure out my problem, don't hesitate to ask me. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific web page opening on the browser? Are you sure this is not about the code? What is the project type?

Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/716757/4321659

Comment: What does your program.cs file look like?

Comment: The application open his own web page (http://localhost:58684/api/...) where he is listening that a client call him. I checked the answer of the page: but the problem is I don't have a Web Tab. I only have

Answer (score 1):

In a asp.net core application there is a folder called properties, in that folder there is a file called launchSettings.json.

Open up the file and you will find json like this:

```
     {
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55556/",
  "sslPort": 0
 }
},
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/getallobjects",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"MyServer": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/getallobjects",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
}
}
```

You can edit this json to adjust what visual studio does when it launches.

So in your case if you want to stop the browser from starting just change the `launchBrowser` property to `false`.

Comment: Ok thak you. This solved my first problem :) Now I only need that the console windows opens directly in VS and not on a separate windows. This would be great :)