# Debug on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, compilation

when I run the debug on visual studio, always opens that a new tab on  browser.
Its possible only actually refresh this tab when I execute a new debug ?

[toolbar Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D0xd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your startup project's properties (Project->{ProjectName} Properties... from the main menu or right click your project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties), then navigate to the Web tab and under Start Action choose Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application.

You will still be able to use any browser (or Fiddler, whatever) to access the running application, but it won't open the browser window automatically, it'll just start in the background and wait for any requests

refer below link
[Stop Visual Studio from launching a new browser window when starting debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-when-starting-debug)