# Debug session ends when browser is closed

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

When I close the browser launched by Visual Studio 2017, debugging an ASP.NET application with F5, the debug session ends

Why?

Comment: The same happens when I am starting my WPF application and close the MainWindow.
I believe it's the normal behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Visual Studio from launching a new browser window when starting debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-when-starting-debug)

Comment: @AndersLindén, hi, if you create a new asp.net web form application, click F5, then close the browser that launched by VS, does this debug session end or not? Please go to Tools-Options-Projects and Solutions-Web Projects and uncheck the option "Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops" to have a try.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Thanks, that is the answer to the question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please go to Tools-Options-Projects and Solutions-Web Projects and uncheck the option "**Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops**" to have a try.